# Session access disable for asp.net bundle requests

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am using asp.net and MVC4 for my application and also i am using bundling for css and js files.

When i look into my trace files, i observed that all my **bundle requests are using session**. i.e, all bundle requests are passing through sessionstatemodule.

My trace looks like below.

```
155. NOTIFY_MODULE_START ModuleName="Session", Notification="REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE", fIsPostNotification="false" 06:59:43.480 
156. AspNetPipelineEnter Data1="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" 06:59:43.480 
157. AspNetSessionDataBegin  06:59:43.480 
158. AspNetSessionDataEnd  06:59:43.996 
159. AspNetPipelineLeave Data1="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" 06:59:43.996 
160. NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION ModuleName="Session", Notification="REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", CompletionBytes="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)" 06:59:43.996 
161. NOTIFY_MODULE_END ModuleName="Session", Notification="REQUEST_ACQUIRE_STATE", fIsPostNotificationEvent="false", NotificationStatus="NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE" 06:59:43.996
```

I think i dont need session access for my bundle requests. How can i disable the session access for my bundle requests?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you want to disable session state for your static resources. For this you can do two things:

1) Disable `SessionState` for `Controller`

For that you need to import `System.Web.SessionState` namespace and you then decorate your controller with following line of code:

```
[SessioState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)
public class HomeController: Controller
{
}
```

For more information you can visit following link:

[Controlling Session State Behavior](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/906b060113-Controlling-Session-Behavior-in-Asp.Net-MVC4.html)

2) Create Static Resources

**IIS Setup:**

Create two website in your inetpub directory.

1. www.domain.com // For main site
2. static.domain.com // Foe static resources

Now point them to same physical directory i.e.

> C:\inetpub\www.domain.com

**Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com**

Redirect any domain.com request to www.domain.com.

> so that any domain.com request must be redirected to www.domain.com
>   because cookie set for domain.com will also be shared by all sub
>   domain including static.domain.com hence it is much important steps

** Code changes**

Add below code in your web.config file:

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="StaticSiteName" value="static.domain.com"/>

  <add key="StaticDomain" value="http://static.domain.com"/>

  <add key="MainDomain" value="http://www.domain.com"/>

</appSettings>
```

use `PreApplicationStartMethod` and `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure` to dynamically register HTTP module in pre-application startup stage

```
public class PreApplicationStart

{

    public static void Start()

    {

        string strStaticSiteName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaticSiteName"];

        string strCurrentSiteName = HostingEnvironment.SiteName;



        if (strCurrentSiteName.ToLower() == strStaticSiteName.ToLower())

        {

            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(StaticResource));

        }

    }

}



public class StaticResource : IHttpModule

{

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)

    {

        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);

    }



    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        string strUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower();



        //HERE WE CAN CHECK IF REQUESTED URL IS FOR STATIC RESOURCE OR NOT

        if (strUrl.Contains("Path/To/Static-Bundle/Resource") == false)            

        {

            string strMainDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainDomain"];

            context.Response.Redirect(strMainDomain);

        }

    }



    public void Dispose()

    {

    }
```

}

**Add an Extension Method**

```
public static class Extensions

{

    public static string StaticContent(this UrlHelper url, string contentPath)

    {

        string strStaticDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StaticDomain"];

        return contentPath.Replace("~", strStaticDomain);

    }

}
```

Now  use `@Url.StaticContent()` from view so that it will render static resource url with static.domain.com whether it is image, script, CSS, or bundles or wherever we want to refer cookieless domain. for e.g.

```
<link href="@Url.StaticContent("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script src="@Url.StaticContent("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.StaticContent("~/bundles/jquery")" type="text/javascript"></script>



<img src="@Url.StaticContent("~/Images/heroAccent.png")" alt="" />
```

Visit below link for full information as article is pretty big:

[Cookie less domain for bundling and static resources](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/10/aspnet-mvc-4-cookieless-domain-for-bundling-and-static-resources.html)

Hope this will help you to achieve your goal.